# Set Atom config.cson location

Tags: path, coffeescript, settings, atom-editor, cson

Is it possible to set Atom `config.cson` location, instead of using the default `~/.atom/config.cson`?

Or at least to be able to use project-relative paths in the `config.cson`?

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is probably on the `ATOM_HOME` environment variable. The `.atom` folder is created relative to the folder defined in this variable. While this might not be too practical in your daily workflow, you can maybe automate it by writing a script.

Further reading: [Controlling Where Customization is Stored to Simplify Your Workflow](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization/#controlling-where-customization-is-stored-to-simplify-your-workflow)

Comment: Yes I know of this approach, was hoping for some better alternative though...